# detecting the step size of a sequence

Tags: r, sequence, seq

Is there a function in base R, or a more elegant way to detect the step size in a vector increases?

At the moment I am using a combination of `diff` and `unique`.

```
xx <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 5)

unique(diff(xx))
# 5
```

Comment: Looks good to me. What's the problem with that approach? If the step size is always the same you could do just `x[2] - x[1]` or `diff(xx)[1]`. Either way, even there is some such special function, your approach looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: just wondering if there is something out there that I have missed

Comment: `rle` also useful when the vector involves different step sizes